# Insert text at the start of mailitem.Body in VSTO Outlook using C#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to insert some text whenever user composing a new mail OR Reply OR ReplyAll. I am able to capture all these 3 events and work on editor after event the occurrence.

Now **I want to insert some text at the beginning of the editor**(the editor box where user type message), for which I tried:

1) Insert method:

```
mailItem.Body = mailItem.Body.Insert(0, "Some Text");
```

This line of code is throwing NullReferenceException.

2) Next, I tried to use Native approach :

```
mailItem.Body = "Some Text " + mailItem.Body;
```

This is appending text at the starting of mail body, but the formatting vanishes which is not acceptable at all.

**Is their is any better solution? Or I can change above used methods with some modifications?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with the plain text `Body` property, use `HTMLBody`. Keep in mind that 2 strings representing 2 well-formed HTML documents cannot be concatenated, they must be merged.

Comment: HTMLBody is working fine. But the appended text is inside Old mail item body in reply and reply all events.The result should be inside new mail item body(refer this image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UCk1yG6aHJwoQs7Q-RQyBGsH6qhj0pHn/view?usp=sharing). 
Maybe I have to capture editor's inspector, if so how I can get inspector of the new mail item body(mail editor)?

Comment: You can use MailItem.GetInspector to retrieve the Word's Document object

Comment: I used : 

Word.Document document = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
Word.Selection selected = document.Windows[1].Selection;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Text : "  + selected.Text);

Which throws The operation failed error. :(

Comment: Use document.Application.Selection.Text. You can play with this in Outlook Spy - open an item, click WordEditor button, select Application property., click Browse, etc.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - can you expand on your suggestion? I am trying to do the same thing as Ank Raw but I'm not understanding how we can only insert into the new mail and not in the inline text under the reply. If you can share some documentation or resources that would be awesome. Thanks!